# BeautifulSoup find().text returns 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' if inside for-loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a webpage using pagination, and I am looping through all the pages on the page. I am trying to store the current page number, using `soup_page_number= soup.find("li", {"class":"page-item active"}).text`, it works as expected, assuming `soup` is an URL with a page number, e.g. https://www.url.com/?p=1.

However, when I attempt to get the page number for all the pages on the site, by looping through all the pages (for the 10 first pages), e.g.:

```
    i=1
for i in range(10):
    url = "https://www.url.com?p="
    url = url + str(i)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
    soup_page_number = soup.find("li", {"class":"page-item active"}).text        
    i+=1
```

Yields the following;

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Which is strange, cause moving the `soup_page_number` outside the for-loop will yield the correct result (but only for one page, page 10 in this case). What is it about the for-loop that causes it to fail?

If necessary, the HTML I am trying to access looks like this:

```
<li class = 'page-item active'>
 <a class='page-link'>9</a>
</li>
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you share website url?

Comment: You need to make your soup inside a ```if response.ok:``` block. There is no guarantee you will get a good ```response``` inside the loop.

Comment: Yes, of course I will share the URL; https://www.ptil.no/tilsyn/granskingsrapporter/.

Comment: Thank you accidas, that is a very good comment. I will implement this into the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe accessing on 'page 10' will work; this is only because you miss the first iteration. The problem is because you are defining 'i = 1', then when you call 'for i in range(10):', 'i' is being reset to the first int in 'range(10)', which is 0.

So actually you are trying to access pages 0-9, rather than 1-10. For what you are wanting, you could do either of the following:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    (code goes here)
```

or

```
i = 1

while i <= 10:
    (code goes here)

    i += 1
```

Comment: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] == list(range(1,11)), and please don't use while here

Comment: Or use a more Pythonic way: ```for i in range(1, 11):``` :-)